# How to create appmenu in using python3 and PyQt?

Tags: python, application-development, appmenu, pyqt

I am looking for a way to create appmenu indicator using python3.2 and pyqt4. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short: Ubuntu 11.10 ships a patched QT that will make a QSystemTrayIcon create an indicator if possible. In older Ubuntu versions you will need a patched version of Qt, and this will make your program a pain to distribute.

Long: There is a patch provided by Canonical to use indicators in Qt, but it's not yet integrated in the official Qt release and it's not likely to happen before Qt 5. Sources: The author [blog](http://agateau.wordpress.com/2011/07/19/statusnotifieritem-for-qt-applications/), an [post](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/6676) in the Qt forum from a Nokia/Trolltech developer.

Ubuntu 11.10 ships with this patch enabled, so a code like this will create an indicator if used in 11.10

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
icon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon("test.png"), app)
menu = QtGui.QMenu()
menu.addAction("Quit", QtGui.qApp.quit)
icon.setContextMenu(menu)
icon.show()
app.exec_()
```

You will need a suitable icon in test.png.

Note that KDE (not plain QT) apps already support indicator by using kdelibs.

There is also the [libindicate-qt](https://launchpad.net/libindicate-qt) project, but I can't find python biddings for it nor any documentation.

Comment: Be sure to install the sni-qt package for this to work. Note that libindicate-qt is not about appindicators: it is mainly used by applications to integrate into the messaging menu (example users include Quassel, Konversation, Kopete and KMail)